# Get current playing song using Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, itunes

Is there a way (ofcourse there is a way, but which way) to get info about the song currently playing in iTunes on a Mac (OS 10.5.8 and OS 10.6) programmatically?

I need this for my Cocoa application.
I use iTunes 8 and Objective-C.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the Scripting Bridge to ask iTunes. iTunes is even the example that [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/) use.